# Progress - Join Tables

Tags: sql, join, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I'm adding some validation checks before I make records to my database and I need to fulfil the following condition:

> Find fieldinfo where fieldinfo.fieldno = 5052
>   Find codetable where codetable.tableno = fieldinfo.tableno and codetable.code = tt-employee.costcode

tt-employee is a temp table , the rest are directly from the db

Since I am new to progress I'm a bit confused - should use a join for that and if so any idea how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: provide us with your schema

Comment: Well uhm the schema is quite big but basically fieldinfo and codetable are tables from the db and tt-employee is a temp table

Comment: Progress 4gl is not SQL -- are you sure that you want a sql tag associated with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things to consider here:

**Validation**

You can add validation either in your logic or in the database itself. How to do it is up to you and what the systems look like. If validation is already present in the database it might be necessary to keep it there.

But if it's not a requirement from your client/boss etc I would personally put all validation in the business logic and NOT in the schema.

Check the database manuals for "validation" if you want to use the database driven approach.

**Joining**

The other issue is that your query is wrong. Progress does indeed support joined queries but not with the `FIND`-statement.

Do like this instead to keep the FIND:

```
FIND fieldinfo NO-LOCK WHERE fieldinfo.fieldno = 5052 NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE fieldinfo THEN DO:
  FIND FIRST codetable NO-LOCK WHERE codetable.tableno = fieldinfo.tableno 
                                 AND codetable.code    = tt-employee.costcode NO-ERROR.
  IF AVAILABLE codetable THEN DO:
    /* Do something */
  END.
END.
```

You could also change it into a `FOR`-statement with a join.

```
FOR EACH fieldinfo NO-LOCK WHERE fieldinfo.fieldno = 5052, 
  FIRST codetable NO-LOCK WHERE codetable.tableno = fieldinfo.tableno 
                           AND codetable.code    = tt-employee.costcode:
  /* Do something */
END.
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed! You helped me out on my previous query as well so I'm very grateful to you!

Comment: "Validation" is one of those 4gl features that "makes a nice demo" but which should almost certainly never be used in real code.  It blurs the distinction between "business logic" and "data access" and is a royal pain in the neck to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @TomBascom I totally agree and perhaps I should have stated that in my response. There wasn't really much background information and sometimes validation is already present in the schema (mostly in older systems) and it MIGHT be beneficial to keep it there. I changed the answer to a more "validation-trigger negative" stance.

Comment: NP, I'm just making sure that nobody accidentally thinks that validation is a "best practice".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
IF  expression  THEN   {block/statement}    [ELSE   {block/statement}]
```

OR

```
IF  expression  THEN DO:   {block}   END.   [ELSE DO:   {block}   END.]
```

See, if that help.

Comment: Cheers dude, but I'm struggling with the expression as "codetable.tableno = fieldinfo.tableno" needs to use the fieldinfo that responds to the first condition and then the codetable from that one needs to match with the tt-employee.costcode

Comment: You can visit http://www.qad.com/Documents/TrainingGuides/printondemand/70-2931A.pdf for more information.